# Eclipse error on running any project: Unknown error: Conversion = '1'

Tags: android, eclipse

I had previously done some testing projects for Android, but now I have a new enviroment and my Eclipse isn't letting me run even an sample project!

I think this can be probably some configuration error, but I've downloaded almost all APIS/SDKs for Android and nothing changed.

Here's some screenshots made for ensuring I'm not doing anything off the limits:
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hmmm .. Did you update the Eclipse ADT plugin as well?

Comment: try changing the eclipse version.....which version of eclipse are ypu using now???please specify....

Comment: @dmon, all installation is new, so I'm using most recent version of ADT.

Comment: @subrussn90, I tried into Indigo first, then I tried Helios... The same error is shown.

Comment: As dmon suggested,try changing the ADT plugin also...

Comment: @subrussn90, please give me some answer like your comment, I'll give you the "Right Answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested into comments, I could not solve the problem, instead I used a Eclipse download I had used in past.